# Validated ssl certificate thowing exception when java app runs

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

I am trying to add an validated SSL certificate to my java app. The Java app acts as a Transformation Service. It listens on a port at a specific URL. It Transforms the body of the request by string find and replace. The Java app then POST that transformed data off to an internal service.

I have added a Self Signed SSL certificate to the app. However this does not work too well. In SoapUI it works fine. When I try call it from a C# application using basicHttpBinding and a HttpWebRequest, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: 
The underlying connection was closed: 
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate 
is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

So I removed that certificate and added a signed certificate. This certificate is currently attached to the domain where the java app is listening on. When I try and run the Java app I get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:   
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
```

Java code that sets the Key and Trust Store:

```
loadConfig();
loadTransforms();

// Set Trust/Key stores
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyFile);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyPassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyFile);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keyPassword);

TransformationServer server = new TransformationServer();
server.runServer(mode);
```

The certificates are stored inside the key and trust stores. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is a 'verified SSL certificate'?

Comment: Well i don't know if you call it verified. But its a not-self signed certificate that is verified (or validated?) by a 3rd party.

Comment: I don't understand. You state in your question that it is self-signed. Now you are stating (I think) that it isn't. A certificate can be *signed* by a certificate authority, if that's what you mean. Please clarify your question.

Comment: And why are you using the same file for the keystore and the truststore? This is very poor practice.

Comment: It's a temporary solution and I am not too worried about how poor / good the practice is. It just need to work (Which it is atm). This app is currently being rewritten in C#. It was a proof of concept to start of with.

Comment: Any other exception in the stack trace? (`caused by: `...)

Comment: Sorry Bruno the exception was very vague. I don't have a lot of experience with ssl certificates hence I threw this question out there. But the looks of things what I implemented worked after I fixed the line endings in the HTTP Header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went about a different solution. I have added the config below to the WinForm App.

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

So Java is still using a Self Signed Cert.

EDIT:
There was something wrong with the line endings in the header of the request. It did not comply with some http RFC standard.